# Internet explorer cannot display the webpage?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer

i have one application that is deployed in IIS at Remote Desktop. if i access that application from local system 
i am getting "Internet explorer cannot display the webpage" and it is running fine in Remote Desktop but not in Local system.

any solution why?

Regards
kumar

Answer (score 1):

Please check the URL which you are using to access the application. You might be using localhost to access the remote IIS site.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Are you deploying this application via remote desktop, or just working on it locally?  Does the app use IIS and does the local server have IIS installed?  Check the event log to see if you are getting any errors logged to see if there is more information.  If the app can run, turn on health monitoring, which logs errors to the event log, to see if that logs anything too.

HTH.

Comment: the application is deployed at IIS at remote desktop .i need to access it from local system. both have the iis .

Comment: OK, if you are trying to access it like a web site, you need to use the IP address for the web site, or by its domain name.  Are you able to do it that way?  What are you using to try to access it?